# How can I use ADO to query access db in Excel custom functions

Tags: excel, ms-access, ado, ms-access-2016, vba

I am trying almost to replicate VLOOKUP functionality with a custom function to fetch data into an Excel Spreadsheet from an Access DB. Never done this before but my understanding is that this ought to work:

```
Function query(lookup_value)

    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sQRY As String
    Dim strFilePath As String

    strFilePath = "Z:\filepath\database.accdb"

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & strFilePath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
    cnn.Open

    sQRY = "SELECT TOP 1 Ethnic FROM central_reference_table WHERE LearnerCode = '" & lookup_value & "'"

    rs.Open sQRY, cnn

    query = rs.Fields(0).Value

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing


End Function
```

The code runs, but returns the generic #VALUE error. I can use the same connection string in a Sub with `Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordSet` and it'll operate as expected, dropping the first row from the db into my worksheet. So it must be the `query = rs.Fields(0).Value` that's the problem, but everything I can find online says that's the correct way to do it, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that code would work as a sub since it should be: `Set rs = New ADODB.RecordSet` and not `Set rs = New ADODB.Record`

Comment: Typo in my tweaks is all, take it as given that I'm not lying when I say "I got it working as a Sub".

Comment: Well, if you correct that, it works as a function too - assuming the db path is correct and there are actually records matching the input criteria.

Comment: *headdesk*. Ah god I suck at life. Thank you - post as an answer and you will get reps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correct this:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Record
```

to this:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.RecordSet
```

then it will work as a function, provided that the db path is correct and there are actually records matching the input criteria. You should really add some error handling for that.